# How to dynamically allocate 2d array when you dont know how many words will user input?

Tags: c

I want to make a program that stores inputed words into a 2D array (it can be as many as you want) and once you input word 'end', program should get out of the while loop. If I for example input these:

```
word1
word2
longer-word
end
```

Then the output should be:

```
List of words are:
word1
word2
longer-word
```

But here's the problem, I obviously dont know how many words will user input ( I dynamically allocated 2d array 5*20, so max 5 words), so what's the "correct" way of dynamically allocating 2D array, do I have to somehow reallocate every time user input new word or what? I really have no idea how to do it.

Here's a code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** allocate(int n, int m) {
    char** arr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * m);

    return arr;
}

void print(char** words, int n, int m) {
    printf("List of words: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }
}
int main() {
    char** words = allocate(5,20);
    char input[20];
    int index = 0;

    while ( strcmp("end", input) ) {
        scanf(" %s", input);

        if (strcmp("end", input) != 0) {
            strcpy(words[index], input);
            index++;
        }
    }
    
    print(words, 5, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

And also I noticed that when you input two words( with space ) it outputs those 2 words separately, so how can i prevent this?

Comment: Don't cast the value returned by `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the array in c/c++ cannot be have a variable so this problem cannot be solved like this, also you can think of this 2d array as 1d array of strings.
this is the solution that i came up with:

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD_SIZE 20

char **allocate(int n, int m) {
    char **arr = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * m);

    return arr;
}

/**
 * first we will check if the count + 1 equal the size and if true we will create new array with a size
 * of size*2 and then move all the words to the new array, if it does not equal then we will copy the new word to the
 * array, also the array is passed by pointer so any change on this array in this scope it will change in the main.
 * @param words the words array that has all the words
 * @param newWord the new word to be inserted
 * @param index the index to insert the nwe word
 * @param size the size of the current array
 * @param wordSize the word size the second dimension in the array
 * @return will return a 2d array.
 */
char** addNewWord(char **words, char *newWord, int index, int *size, int wordSize) {

    if (index == *size) {
        int newSize = *size * 2;
        char **newArray = allocate(newSize, wordSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
            strcpy(newArray[i], words[i]);
        }
        strcpy(newArray[index], newWord);
        *size = newSize;
        return newArray;
    }
    strcpy(words[index], newWord);
    return words;
}

void print(char **words, int n) {
    printf("List of words: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int size = 5;
    char **words = allocate(size, MAX_WORD_SIZE);
    char input[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
    int index = 0;

    while (1) {
        fgets(input, MAX_WORD_SIZE, stdin);
        input[strcspn(input,"\n")] = 0;
        if (strcmp("end", input) != 0) {
            words = addNewWord(words, input, index, &size, MAX_WORD_SIZE);
            index++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    print(words, index);
    return 0;
}
```

the way i did it is i have created a new function that is used to add the new word and if the index is equal the size of the array i have created a new array and copied the content of the first one to the second and this function will return the words array either the same array or the new one, also i have passed the size variable using pointer so i can change it in the function and this change will also change in the main.

--EDIT : i have changed the print from print(words,size) to print(words,index)

--EDIT 2: changed `scanf()` to `fgets` as it is much safer, thanks for [chux - Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica) on the note, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) is why `scanf` is dangerous.

Comment: `scanf(" %s", input);` is as bad as [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: that code was not mine i just wrote the part of the dynamic array, i am more fluent in c++ so i do not know what is a good practice in the c language, i will try and edit the code to include fgets(), thanks for the note

Comment: C is a different language to C++. Don't cast the value returned by `malloc()`. (In C++ you should use `new` not `malloc()` so the need to cast the result should not arise.)

Answer (score 2):

What you need to is guess a reasonable size and allocate that. As you allocate your words you need to check that your limit is not hit. If it will be hit, then you need to `realloc` your array with a bigger size. A common strategy is to double the size each time.

Comment: How do I reallocate it? I am trying it but unsuccessfully. Whats wrong with these :  words = (char**)realloc(words, sizeof(char*) * (n + 20));